# Any Play Framework 2.5 CRUD tutorial

Tags: playframework, crud

I started learn Play Framework 2.5, till now I have learned about MVC concepts, however I does not understand well the Database session on PlayFramework page. Is there any tutorial teaching how to create and access database? Or any CRUD tutorial?

Comment: A number of books are referenced on the play framework website if you're looking for a comprehensive introduction.

Comment: Well the books are outdated, there is a book by Will Sargent which is not done yet, he got 7 chapters so far, but it's not about CRUD, rather about best practice ( title = Play in Practice ), I guess the best starting point are [activator templates](https://www.lightbend.com/activator/templates#filter:CRUD), just search for CRUD, I like the computer database examples and I always keep them around as a [reference](https://www.lightbend.com/activator/templates#filter:computer).

Comment: Thnaks @ALEX_AME It's quite difficult to find any resource about the last play framework version, almost ever I'm limited by Play Framework website. I did not know about that book, I will look for it and read. And I will try those templates.